# Find and solve a recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

In a casino, there are $k(\geq 2)$ colored poker chips, one of which is blue. Find and solve a recurrence relation for the number of ways Joseph can stack n of these chips without consecutive blue chips.

**Attempt**

Let $a_n$ be the number of such arrangements of $n$ poker chips. If we look at the chip, the one underneath it must be of $k-1$ different colours, so we have $(k-1)a_{n-2}$ ways to arrange the rest of the stack. If it's one the other $k-1$ chips on top, we have $a_{n-1}$ ways to arrange the rest of the stack.
Therefore, we're trying to solve the following recurrence relation:

\begin{align*}
a_n=(k-1)a_{n-1}+(k-1)a_{n-2}, n\geq 2
\end{align*}
With $a_0=1$ y $a_1=k$.

Is this correct?

Comment: One of the chips is blue, or one of the colors is blue? Because if it is one blue chip, the condition seems unnecessary, while if it is one color, then there is not enough information.

Comment: This looks good, but you could make your cases more clear in your write-up: The top chip is either blue or it is not. If it is blue, then the first part of your argument gives $(k-1)a_{n-2}$ arrangements. If it is not blue, then the second part of your argument gives $(k-1)a_{n-1}$ arrangements.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The chip is blue. Why does the l condition seem unnecessary?

Comment: If there is only one blue chip, then there can neve be two blue chips next to each other. But your answer indicates this interpretation is not correct.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I guess that's why we can assume that there are at least two blue tiles. Otherwise, there is nothing to do with the exercise.

Comment: To confirm, is this your question: the casino has as at least $n$ chips in each of $k$ colours. The casino makes a stack of $n$ chips, where there are no consecutive blue chips. How many ways can it make the stack? Your recurrence relation accurately describes that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the reccurence relation is
$$a_n=(k-1)(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$$ the solution is given by
$$a_n=\frac {2^{-(n+1)}} K \Big[(K-k-1) (k-K-1)^n+(K+k+1) (k+K-1)^n\big]$$ where $K=\sqrt{(k-1)(k+3)}$.

This generates the sequence
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & k \\
 2 & (k-1) (k+1) \\
 3 & (k-1) \left(k^2+k-1\right) \\
 4 & (k-1)^2 k (k+2) \\
 5 & (k-1)^2 \left(k^3+2 k^2-k-1\right) \\
 6 & (k-1)^3 (k+1) \left(k^2+2 k-1\right) \\
 7 & (k-1)^3 k \left(k^3+3 k^2-3\right) \\
 8 & (k-1)^4 \left(k^2+k-1\right) \left(k^2+3 k+1\right) \\
 9 & (k-1)^4 \left(k^5+4 k^4+2 k^3-5 k^2-2 k+1\right) \\
 10 & (k-1)^5 k (k+1) (k+2) \left(k^2+2 k-2\right)
\end{array}
\right)$$ where interesting patterns can be found.